# Proving general result in limits $\lim\limits_{x\to0}[f(x)+g(x)]=\lim\limits_{x\to0}[f(x)]+\lim\limits_{x\to0}[g(x)]$

Tags: limits

In my book it is mentioned that the proof of this limits result is beyond the scope of the book. But I would love to pursue it's proof anyhow

Here's the result,

$$\lim_{x\to0}[f(x)+g(x)]=\lim_{x\to0}[f(x)]+\lim_{x\to0}[g(x)]$$

The domain and range of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are $\mathbb{R}$

I know this is a too basic result but I don't know how to prove this and I would like to know.
I believe I can derive rest all if I know about this one.

Comment: What's the domain of $f,g$?

Comment: Domain and range are R

Comment: Then take the definition of limit, that is, $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}h(x)=\ell$ if and only if, for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $$|x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow |h(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$$ and notice that $|f(x)+g(x)-f(x_0)-g(x_0)|\leqslant |f(x)-f(x_0)|+|g(x)-g(x_0)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is making it sound more complicated than it is. In general, it will help to think of theorems like this as facts about **error control**.

Specifically, suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)$ each exist - and call them $a$ and $b$, respectively. We want to show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}[f(x)+g(x)]=a+b.$$ Looking at the definition, this means that we need to argue that:

> For any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<\vert x\vert<\delta$ we have $\vert (f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)\vert<\epsilon$.

And our hypotheses are:

- For any $\epsilon_1>0$ there is some $\delta_1>0$ such that whenever $0<\vert x\vert<\delta_1$ we have $\vert f(x)-a\vert<\epsilon_1$.
- For any $\epsilon_2>0$ there is some $\delta_2>0$ such that whenever $0<\vert x\vert<\delta_2$ we have $\vert g(x)-b\vert<\epsilon_2$.

Note that I've given the variables distinct names here - I didn't have to do this, but it winds up clarifying the situation. The "error control" bit comes in when we think about how to manage the quantity $$\vert (f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)\vert,$$ given that we know how to manage the quantities $$\vert f(x)-a\vert\quad\mbox{and}\quad\vert g(x)-b\vert.$$ Specifically, we'll use the **triangle inequality**, which tells us that $$\vert(f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)\vert\le \vert f(x)-a\vert+\vert g(x)-b\vert.$$ (Informally: "the error in the sum is at most the sum of the errors.")

---

OK, that probably looks mysterious. The triangle inequality does indeed connect one of the things we care about with two things we understand, but how does that actually help us solve the problem?

Well, suppose you give me an $\epsilon>0$. I need to find a $\delta>0$ such that $\vert (f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)\vert<\epsilon$ whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ of $0$ (excluding $x=0$ itself). By the triangle inequality, I'll be happy if I can ensure that $$\vert f(x)-a\vert+\vert g(x)-b\vert<\epsilon$$ for all such $x$, which in turn will happen if we know that $$\vert f(x)-a\vert<{\epsilon\over 2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad\vert g(x)-b\vert<{\epsilon\over 2}$$ for all such $x$.

But **those** sorts of constraints are exactly what our **hypotheses** let us get! Specifically, noting that ${\epsilon\over 2}>0$ (since $\epsilon>0$), we have:

- Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)=a$, there is some $\delta_1>0$ such that if $0<\vert x\vert<\delta_1$ then $\vert f(x)-a\vert<{\epsilon\over 2}$.
- Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x)=b$, there is some $\delta_2>0$ such that if $0<\vert x\vert<\delta_2$ then $\vert g(x)-b\vert<{\epsilon\over 2}$.

Combining all this, we have:

> If $\vert x\vert<\delta_1$ *and* $\delta_2$, then $\vert (f(x)+g(x))-(a+b)\vert<\epsilon$.

So what should our $\delta$ be here?

> Just $\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ - go with whichever is smaller!

Comment: That was helpful

Comment: And informative too

Comment: @HowardDickson Thanks! Incidentally, the "$\epsilon\over 2$-and-$\epsilon\over 2$" approach isn't the only way to go here. We could also have worked to guarantee that $\vert f(x)-a\vert<{\epsilon\over 3}$ and $\vert g(x)-b\vert<{2\epsilon\over 3}$, or that $\vert f(x)-a\vert<{\epsilon\over 17}$ and $\vert g(x)-b\vert<{\epsilon\over 42}$; the only important thing is that the sum of the errors is guaranteed to be "small enough" (that is, $<\epsilon$). But those aren't as natural things to shoot for.